# Case-insensitive file check for RewriteCond

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, case-insensitive

I have a .htaccess file which tests for a specific file and runs a PHP script if it's present, and redirects to another web if it's not.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/directory/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.+\.png)$ process.php?file=$1 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.+\.png)$ http://other.website.com/$1
```

I could run the PHP script directly and do the redirect, but it's faster this way. However, I need to make the `RewriteCond` check case-insensitive. I have tried setting all flags and enabling spelling check, but to no avail.

```
RewriteEngine on
CheckSpelling on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/directory/$1 -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+\.png)$ process.php?file=$1 [QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^(.+\.png)$ http://other.website.com/$1
```

The spelling module is enabled in httpd.conf, and .htaccess files can modify all possible settings, but it still works the same as before, not redirecting if a file with different cased filename is entered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `tolower` mapping in your Apache config. First, [create a map](https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/mod/mod_rewrite#rewritemap) for the `tolower` call in your `httpd.conf` (or `apache2.conf` or VHost config):

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
```

Next, in your condition check, convert the `$1` to lowercase:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/directory/${lc:$1} -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+\.png)$ process.php?file=$1 [QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^(.+\.png)$ http://other.website.com/$1
```

Please note that, for the above to work, your files should always be in lower alphabets.

Comment: Good method, but there's already a load of files there, and some may have conflicting names (different case only). I simply can't convert them all to lowercase.